# Why Laravel save method changes updated_at column and other timestamp columns?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I created such table in database.

```
Schema::create('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('count');
    $table->timestamp('expire_date');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now Imagine we have following records in database:

```
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | count | expire_date         | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |   120 | 2018-01-31 19:22:45 | 2018-01-29 17:12:01 | 2018-01-29 19:22:45 |
|  4 |   140 | 2018-02-14 19:05:01 | 2018-01-29 17:20:16 | 2018-01-29 19:05:01 |
| 27 |    10 | 2018-02-17 19:01:10 | 2018-01-29 19:05:01 | 2018-01-29 19:05:01 |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

when I try to edit a record using laravel eloquent:

```
$package = \App\Package::find(1);
$package->count = 100;
$package->save();
```

save method changes both expire_date and updated_at columns to current time!

```
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | count | expire_date         | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |   100 | 2018-01-29 19:32:24 | 2018-01-29 17:12:01 | 2018-01-29 19:32:24 |
|  4 |   140 | 2018-02-14 19:05:01 | 2018-01-29 17:20:16 | 2018-01-29 19:05:01 |
| 27 |    10 | 2018-02-17 19:01:10 | 2018-01-29 19:05:01 | 2018-01-29 19:05:01 |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

why expire_date value changes without even touching it?!!!

Comment: @TimLewis I'm asking why expire_date is changing.

Comment: Maybe you are using another package, and that package changes the field

Comment: @MahdiYounesi no, i found the reason. it's because of mysql Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: You should use Datetime for that 'expire_at' column instead.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look your table DDL,it would be

```
expire_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

`expire_date` default value is current timestamp.
all you need do is, change `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to null.

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN expire_date DEFAULT NULL
```

or before you create:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/be09eac00a2f750dc2d2209078cf61ae2eee85a1/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L647

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d598a6630208b054376527e41848c106f4297b2b/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/ColumnDefinition.php#L26

```php
$table->timestamp('expire_date')->useCurrent(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates):

> The `save` method may also be used to update models that already exist in the database. To update a model, you should retrieve it, set any attributes you wish to update, and then call the save method. Again, the `updated_at` timestamp will automatically be updated, so there is no need to manually set its value

So, Eloquent updates only the `updated_at`. If `expire_date` is also updated, it means Eloquent events are used in the app or something similar is happening (like DB [updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) it).